# output this vba into cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()

Dim s() As Double

ReDim s(5 + 1, 5 + 1) As Double

For i = 1 To 5 + 1

    For j = i To 5 + 1

        s(i, j) = 0.05 * 1.2 ^ (j - 1) * 0.8 ^ (i - 1)

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: i need to output this into the cells or range but i am not able to, i need to know how this works, i took it out of the internet.

Comment: Did the internet really have `ReDim s(5 + 1, 5 + 1) As Double`? (doesn't seem like you got this from a reputable source).

Comment: they had it n instead of 5

Comment: I'm quite lazy and usually write 6 instead of 5+1. Also you don't need Redim, you can just Dim if you know the size up front. `range("a1").resize(6,6).value=s`.

Comment: ^ Except the array is actually 7x7 because it's equivalent to `ReDim s(0 to 6, 0 to 6) As Double`, so you'd use `.Resize(7, 7)`, or fix your array to be the right size.

Comment: Thank you SJR that will do , i will try now to figure how it works by changing the numbers thank you

Comment: @BigBen - good point. Or use `ubound(s,1)` and it will work for any size.

Comment: thank you BigBen i will keep that in mind, but when i change the "5" to "n" is gives some error i am not sure why.

Comment: You'll need to assign a value to `n` before you `Redim`.

Comment: yes that is right i assigned the value after Redim , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Cells(i, j) = 0.05 * 1.2 ^ (j - 1) * 0.8 ^ (i - 1)
```

Comment: This negates the advantage of using an array.

Comment: this is giving different output why?

Comment: different that what?

Comment: one value is missing not there.

Comment: Which value is missing? I get 1 value in Col A, 2 values in col B, ... 6 values in col F.